# Can I change the shock size of the irf() - function?

Tags: r, regression, var

I estimated the following VAR-model which I want to interpret using IRFs.

As I understood the irf() function  uses the estimated standard deviation of the disturbance term for the impulse as the magnitude of the shock.

Is it possible to change the magnitude of a shock that R uses? e.g. a shock of 1 to each variable ?

```
vardata1 <- cbind(DBausgaben1ts, DBIP1ts)

Var1 <- VAR(vardata1, p = 3, type = "none", exogen = sdd)

Var1irf <- irf(Var1, n.ahead = 10, ortho = TRUE)
```